# Erro ao tentar inserir uma informação no banco de dados mysql

Tags: android, mysql

Tenho as seguintes tabelas

```
Produto {
  idproduto 
  nome
  preco
}
Promocao {
  descricao
  datainicio
  datatermino
  id_produto_fk
}
```

Ao tentar inserir uma nova promocao me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mercado_db`.`promocao`, CONSTRAINT `produto_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`id_produto_fk`) REFERENCES `produto` (`idproduto`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está tentando inserir uma promoção para um produto que não existe. Você já deu uma olhada se no seu `insert` de promoção, o valor passado para o campo `id_produto_fk` é um valor que existe na tabela `produto.idproduto`?

Comment: Cara fiz alguns testes aqui, tenho um app que envia um objeto Promocao para o metodo inserir com os dados acima. No app eu imprimo o promocao.id_produto_fk e aparece o id do produto no componente mas antes de enviar ao banco no método inserir coloquei um print do objeto a salvar e no id_produto_fk aparece 0, não sei mais o que fazer para resolver isso.